# C libpcap API casting packet to struct(confusing)

Tags: c, casting

After reading this tutorial

`(https://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html)`

On the very bottom the author is casting a `u_char *packet` pointer into a struct.

Does such casting work like this

Lets say I have this struct

```
struct 16bits{ 
 int8_t a;
 int8_t b;
 }
```

and a 16bit sequence

```
0001 0011 0111 1111
```

and if I cast it to 16bits struct it would look like this ?

```
a = 0001 0011
b = 0111 1111
```

The question is if I understand the authors casting correctly.

I am aware about padding in structs, but lets think the compiler doesn't add it for a moment

Comment: Yes - though padding as you mention, and possible endiand-ness issues. The cast "pretends" this first byte is the start of the struct.

Comment: A quick scan of the linked code reveals what appears to me to be a lot of undefined behavior and strict aliasing violations.

Answer (score 1):

> Lets say I have this struct
>
> ```
> struct 16bits{ 
>  int8_t a;
>  int8_t b;
>  }
> ```
>
> and a 16bit sequence
>
> ```
> 0001 0011 0111 1111
> ```
>
> and if I cast it to 16bits struct it would look like this ?
>
> ```
> a = 0001 0011
> b = 0111 1111
> ```

I assume you mean something like:

```
// this points at your 16-bit sequence
unsigned char *input_data = ...

struct 16bits *output_data = ( struct 16bits * ) input_data;

uint8_t a_bits = output_data->a;
uint8_t b_bits = output_data->b;
```

In general, no you cannot assume you can do that.  In general, that would be [a strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and undefined behavior.  The "strict aliasing" rule basically says you can't treat memory as something it's not - but with the exception that you can always access anything one `char` at a time.  An `int` is not a `float`.

In addition, as you mention there can be padding between fields in a structure.

In your specific example, though, it's almost certain to "work" on just about any platform, though, because `int8_t` is almost certainly a `signed char`, there's almost certainly no padding in the `struct 16bits`, and any memory can always be accessed as a `char` value.

Replace the `char` types with types such as `double` or `int64_t`, though, and you can run into alignment as well as padding issues.  On some platforms, such strict aliasing violations can cause code to fail with `SIGSEGV` or `SIGBUS`.

Assuming 8-bit `char` values so `int8_t` is actually a `char`, a fully standards-compliant way of accessing any data type as applied to your 16-bit sequence as two 8-bit values would be

```
// assume this points to your 16-bit sequence
unsigned char *input_data = ...

// create a structure that we can actually copy the bits into
struct 16bits output_data;

memcpy( &output_data, input_data, sizeof( output_data ) );
```

Note that if the structure contains elements of a type other that `char`, there may be padding.  And if you use something like `#pragma pack` to eliminate the padding, [you can wind up with code that doesn't run on some platforms.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793511/are-there-performance-issues-when-using-pragma-pack1)

Code such as that in the link you provided is rampant - and it's actually undefined behavior.  But it "works" because the x86 platform most popular published code is written on is very, very, very forgiving of misaligned accesses (although there is still a performance penalty).  But that type of code won't work well at all on any platform that does have alignment requirements.  Just [Google `pragma pack sigbus`](https://www.google.com/search?q=pragma%20pack%20sigbus) and you'll find lots of examples of programmers surprised when code that ran just fine on x86 fails on ARM or SPARC platforms, for example.